# Windows Mobile speech communication in a intranet

Tags: windows-mobile, microphone, intranet

How to use microphone based on windows mobile devices to communicate with each other in a intranet like a interphone communication? I do not have the thought yet.

Comment: Does your device even have a microphone?

Comment: I have several different mobile devices, but none have a microphone. You will probably have to get with the manufacturer about how to capture audio from the device using the manufacturer's SDK first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Voice-over-IP application to communicate within your network. Just use Walky-Talky like apps like http://handheld.softpedia.com/get/System-Utilities/Communications/iTalkie-20330.shtml

If you are a experienced Windows Mobile C/C++ coder you may write such app yourself.